# Get::noopen: Cannot open CloudObjectLoader` error when running Mathematica on remote cluster

Tags: parallelization, remote-access

I have been running *Mathematica* on a remote cluster for quite sometime. Recently, any jobs that call `LaunchKernels[]` for parallelization return the error

> Get::noopen: Cannot open CloudObjectLoader`

in the output file and terminate. Here's an example that produces this error on the cluster.

```
LaunchKernels[]

$ProcessorCount

$KernelCount

Do[s=ParallelTable[i+l,{i,10}];,{1000}]
```

Is the solution to this problem as simple as having the cluster administrator create a Wolfram Cloud account? Thanks!

Comment: I do see this error from time to time when I launch parallel kernels on the local machine, but it has never caused any negative effects (such as the subkernels exiting). It also doesn't happen consistently. I did report it to Wolfram but they said that they cannot reproduce it. I have two suggestions for you: 1. Definitely do report the problem to Wolfram, and give as much information as you can to ensure they can reproduce it. 2. Make sure that the subkernels terminating and this error are truly correlated. They may have entirely separate causes.

Comment: Could you try `RebuildPacletData[]` and see if that fixes the issue?

Comment: Today I got this message for the first time after more than 2 years on a local Windows computer with 4 cores: `Get::noopen :  Cannot open CloudObjectLoader`.`

Comment: I am having this CloudObjectLoader not loading issue and not related to parallel processing. I found that it can be temporarily solved by forcing Mathematica to load the package: Get["C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\11.0\\SystemFiles\\Links\\CloudObject\\Kernel\\CloudObjectLoader.m"]

Comment: I found that the  issue is solved by deleting an incomplete CloudObject paclet at "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Paclets\Repository\CloudObject-11.1.1321".